# Why does my sorting method for Bigdecimal numbers fails to sort?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, bigdecimal

**problem :** i employed a certain sorting method, but it didn't work out as i expected and i fail to understand where did i possibly err.

**My code** took input(which are numbers) as Strings into an string array and then converted them into Bigdecimal numbers while i compared them, and then rearranged them accordingly in the array as strings

**the code in question:**

```
 String s[]={-100, 50, 0, 56.6, 90, 0.12, .12, 02.34, 000.000};

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for (int j =i+1; j<n; j++) 
             {
              BigDecimal  d = new BigDecimal(s[j]); 
              BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(s[i]);
                if(a.compareTo(d)==-1) 
                    {
                        String m = s[j];
                        s[j]=s[i];
                        s[i]=m;
                    }
              }
        }
         //output :90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, .12, 0.12, 0, 000.000, -100

        //expected output :90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100
```

Constraints : `s[n]` should be a string array and if two inputs have same values they should be listed in the array in the same order we entered them.

i don't understand why 0.12 and .12 are not output in the same order as i entered them, if the algorithm is somewhere wrong then even 0 and 000.000 should not have  have appeared in the same order as i entered them, but instead they did.

Comment: Why doesn't your String array contain Strings?

Comment: actually it's the question constraint, that numbers have to be entered as strings

Comment: I think you should surround them in `"` to make them string literals (e.g. `{"-100", "50"`...). Maybe I'm missing some kind of fancy java syntax here, but it blows my mind that this compiles.

Comment: Don't reinvent sorting. Just wrap your strings into an object containing the string and its decimal equivalent, then sort these objects, then extract the strings.

Comment: mm...actually the question said users have to input numbers, into an string type array, in my code i did it with scanner class, but to shorten it, here i put it this way.....should i edit it ? in actual code i put it  s[i]=sc.next();

Comment: @ArnavDas making the code simpler to make the question simpler to understand is not a problem. But that doesn't mean it shouldn't compile. You're storing integers and numbers in a String array, so that can't compile.

Comment: i got my mistake, i won't repeat next time @JBNizet

Comment: What's wrong with the output? Seems sorted to me. Some of the values are equal so it's still ok.

Comment: @androiddeveloper the question required me to rearrange values in descending manner and if i come across numbers like 0.1 or 000.1 then they were to be output in the same order as i had entered them, which isn't the case with 0.12 and .12 , i inputted 0.12 first and then .12 yet it outputted .12 first and then 0.12

Comment: @ArnavDas Oh I see. So why did it occur this way, then?

Comment: @androiddeveloper well I don't understand it... that's why I posted this question

Comment: @ArnavDas But I see you've accepted an answer, which means you know why it happens, as you solved the issue...

Comment: @androiddeveloper true I got the answer, that is the expected output but where does my logic err in my code I am yet to ascertain

Comment: @ArnavDas I guess the only way to find out, is to debug it yourself. At some point of the so many steps it has, it will switch the "0.12", ".12" locations. Maybe try on a smaller array. Maybe just "0","90","0.12", ".12" . My guess is that you will find the answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you want to use String numbers, you will have to wrap them in quotations, but your sorting can be much more readable. I would suggest the following

```
    String[] numbers ={"-100", "50", "0", "56.6", "90", "0.12", ".12", "02.34", "000.000"};
    List<BigDecimal> decimalList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s: numbers){
        decimalList.add(new BigDecimal(s));
    }
    Collections.sort(decimalList);
    Collections.reverse(decimalList);     // edit , forgot this line
    decimalList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That's definitely the better answer for a newbie because each step becomes more clear - no matter that there are more characters are used. At the end it counts that code is readable and hence easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Stream` and pass a custom comparator to `sorted` and then `collect` and print. Like,

```
String s[] = { "-100", "50", "0", "56.6", "90", "0.12", ".12", "02.34", "000.000" };
System.out.println(Stream.of(s)
        .sorted((a, b) -> new BigDecimal(b).compareTo(new BigDecimal(a)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

And I get (as requested)

```
90, 56.6, 50, 02.34, 0.12, .12, 0, 000.000, -100
```

Comment: Do you think that's better readable than the Stefan's answer?

Comment: @ThomasS. I think it's more readable, prints what OP asked for and sorts correctly (if we're comparing the results, Stefan's produces `-100,
0,
0.000,
0.12,
0.12,
2.34,
50,
56.6,
90` - which isn't correct).

Comment: Upvoted your answer, because it uses full potential of Java 8 functions and less code. I think mine is better readable for entry level coders, edited to produce correct results.

Comment: For a real-world problem I think this solution is harder to read, harder to debug and has a larger overhead because of more created temporary objects (e.g. for each comparison 2 BigDecimals are created, not for each entry in the list as for Stefan's answer).