# Why does this sorting method behave differently for certain inputs?

Tags: java, sorting, bigdecimal, compareto

As the question title suggests i am unable to understand why does my sorting method behave differently for separate inputs

**Question constraints :** A string array is to be used for input of `n` numbers, and then rearrange them in descending order and if you come across numbers having equal values like `000.0` and `.0` , they should be listed in the same order as i entered them and also should be output in same format as they were entered.

**My Question :** for `n=2` when i entered `0.12,.12`, my code output `0.12,  .12`, but while for `n=3` when i entered `1, 0.12,.12` it output `1,.12, 0.12`(instead of `1,0.12,.12`) so, why does this occur ? And can any slight modification in my code can rectify this glitch ?

**Code :**

```
String[] s= new String[n];
     //input :
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    s[i]=sc.next();
      //Sorting :
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    BigDecimal  d=new BigDecimal(s[i]); 
    for (int j =i+1; j<n; j++) 
    {
        BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal(s[j]);
        if(d.compareTo(a)==-1) 
        {
             String m = s[j];
             s[j]=s[i];
             s[i]=m;
         }
    }
}
//Output :
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    System.out.println(s[i]);
```

The `compareto` method when handling `Bigdecimal` type numbers considers `0.12` and `.12` as equal, but when handling `String` type variables doesn't consider `.12` and `0.12` as equal, so while comparing only i converted them into `Bigdecimal` types, but for displaying i kept them as `Strings` since `Bigdecimal` types round off `.12` as `0.12` but `Strings` don't.

Comment: Why do you keep using your own sorting method instead of doing what you were being told to do in your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114295/why-does-my-sorting-method-for-bigdecimal-numbers-fails-to-sort. Also, why don't you indent your code, making it unreadable?

Comment: @JBNizet no i used that process and all outputs were perfectly fine and expected, i was just like a bit Little more curious.... As to where did I err...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine, using the test code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] s= {"1","0.12",".12"};
        int n = 3;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

                BigDecimal  d=new BigDecimal(s[i]);

                for (int j =i+1; j<n; j++){

                  BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal(s[j]);

                        if(d.compareTo(a)==-1){
                            String m = s[j];
                            s[j]=s[i];
                            s[i]=m;

                        }
                    }
                }
                  //Output :
                     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                System.out.println(s[i]);

    }

}
```

Which you can see here:

https://www.jdoodle.com/a/cGZ